# Cannot access key in props when variable passed to function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have two `interfaces` like this

```
interface Cat {
    name: string,
    color: string,
    feedingTimes: number[]
}

interface Dog {
    name: string,
    height: number,
    dateOfBirth: number,
}
```

I then create an `arry`

```
const ANIMALS = [{...} as Cat, {...} as Dog]
```

Then I am mapping through `ANIMALS` calling the `function`foo()`.

```
ANIMALS.map((animal, index) => {foo(animal, identifier: getIdentifier(index)})
```

Here are `foo()` and `getIdentifier()`. `getIdentifier()` only returns a string, based on the `index`.

```
getIdentifier = (index: number):string => {...};

const foo = (animal: Cat | Dog) => {
    if(identifier === 'cat') {
        const {name, color, feeding} = animal
    } else {
        const {name, height, dateOfBirth} = animal
    }
}
```

This fails. I cannot access `let {name, color, feeding} = animal` nor `let {name, height, dateOfBirth} = animal`. I am getting

> Property '...' does not exist on type 'Cat | Dog'.

Where `...` are `name, color, feeding` or `name, height, dateOfBirth`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type it like this to declare that when the `identifier` is `'cat'` the type of the `animal` is of type `Cat`

```js
type FooParams = [
    animal: Dog,
    identifier: 'dog'
] | [
    animal: Cat,
    identifier: 'cat'
]

type Foo = (...params: FooParams) => void

const foo: Foo = (animal, identifier) => {
    if (identifier === 'cat') {
        const { name, color, feedingTimes } = animal
    } else {
        const { name, height, dateOfBirth } = animal
    }
}
```

In your code you don't show any relation between the animal and the identifier

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gWAFDKHIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmANPkcggPYA2HUVt9EM1ZEYECABNGAFWDlqVEAFdSAI2gBtALr4AvvnyhIsRCgAiHBthGES5fnUYsCRABYRgDV2EUr1UZzYJDAgAeRgAIWAoMFdfNWhnfTx8ThBaZABBADkASQBZTIAZAGVkAF5kDSxdZDhqNAwmbFr65AsGHRS8MABPAAcUADEODgAFOCgyBsqNGzqQOTguKg7AomAJCHBgGGBoKgByCUtD-C1kAB8q+bhF0mWqdDB1wk3tsF39vmRDhAwznguvg+oNkCMOBVkAAKAB08P6k2mVAhEympGoAEoKgA+ZAANw4mwMeDSGRgoxRoyh0LuSy4zXeOz20Gx5TxuBcbxgMKZnxZUAq5UqfwB2M5bDYZMwWGIZAgzU4PACyDEkhkcggDVqlTpDy480lRuNJtNkoA9ObkAA9AD881qEC41BQEuN0uwcvIzXcnm8zWCkHCURirmQOoW9MNZpjsaNlpt9q54b0JK2CC4kxQMCUIAQnw4IGQDAgYFyW2Z32hwHi-kxR3+YEOV1+JwYgPwOQKxRKsIe-WhtPuy0ZIC2AA82RzVaMh-TmiWyxX+VXQBPMdjdJj8EA)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you assumed Cat | Dog means: "of type cat or of type dogs" whereas it means of type "Cat | Dog" which is a new type, representing an union of both types.

It doesn't mean it has all property of both types, it means it can be either type. At this point the compiler doesn't know which one it is.

Which means it only has the one property: "name".

Typescript has a feature which allows the compiler to guess the type based on an attribute, if you use a switch on it. Here is a working example:

```
interface Cat {
    typeOfAnimal: 'cat'
    name: string,
    color: string,
    feedingTimes: number[]
}

interface Dog {
    typeOfAnimal: 'dog'
    name: string,
    height: number,
    dateOfBirth: number,
}

const ANIMALS = [{name: "cat", color: "red", feedingTimes: [1, 2]} as Cat, {name: "name", height: 2, dateOfBirth: 2} as Dog]

const foo = (animal: Cat | Dog) => {
    switch(animal.typeOfAnimal) {
        case('cat'): 
            return (animal.name, animal.color, animal.feedingTimes)
        case('dog'):
            return (animal.name, animal.height, animal.dateOfBirth)
        
    }    
}

foo(ANIMALS[1])
foo(ANIMALS[0])
```

it also works with "if"s, like this:

```
const foo = (animal: Cat | Dog) => {
    if(animal.typeOfAnimal == 'cat') {
        const {name, color, feedingTimes} = animal
    } else {
        const {name, height, dateOfBirth} = animal
    }
}
```

you can also just typecast it back