# Cannot access props passed in object as function parameter TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have `interfaces` like this

```
interface CatProps {
    feedingTime: number,
    color: string,
    old: boolean
}

interface DogProps {
    height: number,
    breed: string,
    allergies: boolean
}

interface Cat {
    name: string,
    data: CatProps[]
}

interface Dog {
    name: string,
    data: DogProps[]
}

type AnimalState = {
    dog?: Dog[],
    cat?: Cat[]
}

export interface AnimalStateEntries {
    allStatesArrays: Dog[] | Cat[]
    allStatesSingular: DogProps | CatProps
}
```

}

I then map through an `object` (`ANIMALS`) of type `AnimalState` like this, calling `functionOne()` and `functionTwo()`

```
const ANIMALS: AnimalState = {...}

(Object.keys(ANIMALS) as Array<keyof AnimalState >).map((identifier, index) => {
    let animal = ANIMALS[identifier]
    if(animal) {
          let {name, data} = animal
          functionOne(name, data, identifier)  
    }
})


const functionOne = (name: string, data: AnimalStateEntries['allStatesArray'], identifier: keyof AnimalState) => {
    return data.map(information => functionTwo(information, identifier)

})

const functionTwo = (data: AnimalStateEntries ['allStatesSingular'], identifier: keyof AnimalState) => {
    if(identifier === 'dog') {
         const {height, breed, allergies} = data
    } else {
         const {feeding, color, old} = data
    }
}
```

But, when I try to access `const {height, breed, allergies} = data` and  `const {feeding, color, old} = data` in `functionTwo()` I am getting

> Property '...' does not exist on type 'CatProps | DogProps   Property '...' does not exist on type 'DogProps'.

Where `...` are the props I am trying to access.
If I change `const functionTwo = (data: any, identifier: keyof AnimalState) => {...}`

It works. Why is that?

Comment: The compiler isn't aware of any connection between the values of data and identifier. Have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html for some of the options you have for expressing it. But you've [already been told this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75992667/3001761).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(identifier === 'dog') {
```

gives Typescript no idea about the type of `data`. You will have to use some type narrowing which typescript understands.

Try to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isDog(identifier: 'dog' | 'cat', data : AnimalStateEntries ['allStatesSingular']): data is DogProps {
  if(identifier === 'dog')
  return true;
  return false;
}
```

Change your if condition like:

```
if(isDog(identifier,data)) {
         const {height, breed, allergies} = data
    }
```

[TS Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=54&ssc=2&pln=50&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzABSgewA4DOyA3gLABQyVyMEEAJqAOYAqwAthAFzIgCu7AEbQANBWrIEOADY4oPAmCjMxlajPo9BOGRDggKAXwoVQkWIhQARHE2z4iZNVQAWEYExdge-IaPHUglB0msiKyiBMqhJw0tLQTMAQBFo68fpGJuRm0PBIaBgkAVQgcJwKSirFyPQYcDzoWLiEANoAupnkpuC5lsg2TEXOvGXcYZWR0dS1YPX9tvatHeTGXeRgAJ54KACCIByxAMqzkMgAvEMS9LYA-DwD7VNUCBh3BWDtnRQQAB54cmBkDkLPk9gdpMcMBAAKLgZTJS7UWIQk7JHZQKBwDYpeZMdrIAA+70+w2RkMgBEOzD40jg8lxiyIRMajK+5CkIEUyB2ADkAJIAWR2ABlDjwwewjqjzkNDABuLIACgA8oIAFYQBBgAB0AGsINjFbzBSLDgBKZBwIjozEbAA8+o2OBg3P2kpRUOQAD4zdrJXhFYrgPQIOBgDAklARECQCGfhazl7EVR4oD9OCZcahaKWsHQ2Bw5HlhJw4r0+6LU4JNXkKmSDU6oYZeXYtUazA+CAtcAcCAWAB3HCKmZwaN5sMR6AW5DVVaGM1ZCgcrkdrsF3vKkAoC6K0rlcYRKIN2bit1SqGwyrJFoAcjJqIINqxN7aY5DE8jPEdztd4PJEATJMq2oYIwD4KAQGPOA-TgANQBgORJXXSDExoTtu17Ach3gxCMB7EA33zQspyyecslXDDIOAAgBiDd8C0nekb2uJgb0JZAbxeMAb2jEdkFPP9UUveEiFve8oUpalaSgF8zR4PjqIZZpHACUtxwYyNzjOC5mNsG8FzUUDwMgpQ+AgBVDIgMCIJoWICHMtll0BCjkKwmVhzqAT3X-YSklEu84n-STIhpOkX0Ij9oC-A0fwlc9IEA5MgRgIMaNsOiiMYkQRzNSs2wkJySDcDwvGjIIQmjZEEj8psLhHWdkAgaR7KS6tCuIWgGBUSQZDkaMNFqqDZyMZAgA)

Comment: Why wouldn't you `return identifier === "dog"`?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe haha, yes :P